# Get List of Values (LOV) from sql query in JasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

In Oracle Reports I am able to run reports which get parameters by querying from database. In PHP/mySQL I am able to populate data in HTML dropdown menu by using sql query.

I would like to do the same in my JasperReports, either using JasperReport Studio or using JasperReport Server input controls. The current LOV I am able to get using JReport 'Input Controls' makes me enter options manually.

This is what I am trying to explain in words:

[image: Get Jasper report to show LOV/dropdown menu to display data from my database table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an Input Control in JasperServer. When in the Create Input Control page of the wizard choose a Type of Single-select Query. This will enable you to enter a SQL query so you can provide a list of options from the database.

There is also a Multi-select Query alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will check this tomorrow. 
If it works will mark your answer as correct (y)

Comment: My apologies for the late response. Just got to check the answer.

The list of values does give the ID's LOV, but for some reason the ID's text is not being displayed. Can u take a look -> http://imagebin.ca/v/2PEYBuAYJLGc ?

Comment: Additionally, can this also be done using JasperReport Studio? I am unable to find the Single/Multi select query in the studio.

Comment: If the text is not being displayed I would think that is because you didn't click the 'Add' in the final screen of the input control wizard - it's easy to miss!

Comment: I don't this is possible if just running the report in Jaspersoft Studio

Comment: You solved it again ... it was the 'Add' in the final screen. thanks